# How many nested anonymous methods are allowed?

Tags: javascript, nested, anonymous-function

My question is in JavaScript how many nested anonymous methods are allowed as each call to a method stores the address and state of the calling method on stack? For example

```
$(document).on("click", "#someID", function() {
    $("#someDiv").slideUp("fast", function() {
        $("someOtherDiv").slideDown("fast", function() {
            //And So on...
        });
    });
});
```

So because of the memory limit there must be a limit on the number of nested methods.

Comment: I am guessing, this number could vary from implementation to implementation.

Comment: I'd guess this limit is fairly large.

Comment: @thefourtheye what do you mean by implementation?

Comment: #thg435 so i don't need to worry for nesting to limit 30 or so?

Comment: The nearest limit would be your tolerance to the increasing indentation.

Comment: @pronox: 30 nested functions is definitely something to worry about.

Comment: @thg435 how come? storing 30 return addresses and states shouldn't be that hard to store on stack? or am i missing something?

Comment: @pronox i think thg435 is saying that if you are nesting 30 levels of anonymous functions is because you have a problem with your design.